# Where can I get my unique taxpayer ref number from?

Tags: united-kingdom, self-employment

I'm already registered for self assessment, but I don't know what my UTR number is because I'm abroad for 6 months and don't have those documents with me.

Since I should already have a self assessment unique tax ref number, can I just phone up HMRC and get it from them?

Answer (score 1):

You can always contact your local tax office. Most major cities have a tax office, although I guess you can just contact the head office too.  Have as much of your tax information to hand (such as national insurance number, date of birth, address etc). Your tax office will then be able to send you a reminder of your UTR number.  I don't believe they'll be able to give it to you over the phone though.  Hopefully there is someone at your UK address who can receive the mail and read it to you?